Binomial Random Variable with Varying Probability of Success
Suppose you are flipping a coin whose probability of heads is $\frac{i}{j}$ where $i$ is the number of heads up to that toss and $j$ is the total number of tosses. Assume the coin lands tails the first time and heads the second. Thus the probability of heads on the third toss is $\frac{1}{2}$. What is the probability of getting exactly $35$ heads in 50 tosses?
My first thought was to use a binomial RV, but then you have a variable chance of success after each toss. You could bash this out with a computer since there are a finite amount of cases. My best thought is there is some sort of recursive solution, but I can't see what to do. Is there a known distribution this follows?

Presumably you mean something like "exactly $35$ heads after $50$ tosses", since if you carry on tossing you will eventually get $35$ heads (with probability $1$).
Anyway, this is functionally equivalent to a Pólya urn. Try to prove by induction that after $n$ tosses the number of heads is equally likely to be any number between $1$ and $n-1$.

Wikipedia says the probability of exactly (x + n_1) white balls (heads) and (y + n_2) black balls (tails) is: $\binom{n}{n_1}\frac{x^{\bar n_1}y^{\bar n_2}}{(x+y)^{\bar n}}$. We have x = y = 1 since we have 1 of each to start. We do a total of n = 48 flips after this. We need 34 heads, so $n_1 = 34$. Plugging these in gives: $\binom{48}{34}\frac{1}{(2)^{\bar {48}}}$.
Is this correct or am I misinterpreting since this number is near zero?

That Wikipedia article is impressively obfuscated. It would be really helpful if it started with the elegant results which hold in the most simple and easy case. When $x=y=1$ (which is your case), the distribution after $n$ tosses is uniform on ${1,2,\dots,n-1}$, as EspeciallyLime says. (The term $1^{\bar{n}_1}$ works out to be $n_1!$, not $1$).

I am struggling on the application of the inductive hypothesis. I see the probabilities for the n+1 flip given we had k heads in the first n flips, but I don't see how I can do this generally.

@ Especially Lime: Great answer! I recently posted a question on Polya Urn - can you please check it out if you have time? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4953261/relationship-between-martingales-and-picking-balls-from-a-hat  thank you!
